# What is the everyday thunder?

Tags: riddle

> The everyday thunder is coiled like a snail,
>   But just pull it out and it rumbles away.
>   It's so versatile! Being used as a lid,
>   As cookware and packing and sometimes even a hat.

What is it?

*Part of the [everyday object series](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=body%3A%22everyday+object+series%22+is%3Aquestion)*

Comment: @Brandon_J Why did you remove the rhyme tag?

Comment: Because the puzzle doesn't appear to rhyme. Maybe I missed something?

Comment: I see "-ail", "-ay", "-id", and "-at". In the middle of lines I see "-er", "-out", "-ile", and "-ing". None of _those_ rhyme...perhaps there was something else intended in the puzzle?

Comment: @Brandon_J OK, I admit that this one doesn't rhyme that much. It probably sounds rhymy-er in my non-native dialect than it actually is ;-)

Comment: :) It probably does. Nice riddle!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like

> aluminum foil

The everyday thunder is coiled like a snail,

> It's packaged rolled up into cylinders.

But just pull it out and it rumbles away.

> It can sound thunderous when shaken.

It's so versatile! Being used as a lid,

> Over jars or pots as covering.

As cookware and packing and sometimes even a hat.

> As food foil trays, packing sandwiches, or a tin foil hat to keep out signals ...